# How to `animate` an object using web-sys and js-sys

Tags: rust, frontend, css-animations, web-sys

I've been trying to emulate this javascript code in a frontend framework and haven't been able to get much traction.

```js
window.onpointermove = event => { 
  const { clientX, clientY } = event;
  
  blob.animate({
    left: `${clientX}px`,
    top: `${clientY}px`
  }, { duration: 3000, fill: "forwards" });
}
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```rust
fn animate_blob_to_follow_mouse(event: MouseEvent, blob: Element) {
    let client_x = event.client_x();
    let client_y = event.client_y();
    let keyframes = js_sys::Array::new();

    let keyframe = JsValue::from_str(&format!(
        "{{left: '{}px', top: '{}px'}}",
        client_x, client_y
    ));
    keyframes.push(&keyframe);

    let effect = KeyframeEffect::new_with_opt_element_and_keyframes(
        Some(&blob),
        Some(keyframes.as_ref())
    ).unwrap();

    // Set duration and fill directly on the KeyframeEffect
    let animation = Animation::new_with_effect_and_timeline(Some(&effect), None).unwrap();
    animation.play().unwrap();
}
```

But at runtime this fails to even construct the KeyframeEffect object because `keyframes` is not of type Object. However, [the documentation for Object](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/struct.Object.html) seems to require an object to create an object.

Furthermore, [the docs for AnimationTimeline](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.AnimationTimeline.html) seem to say that this object is only useful for `current_time()` which doesn't seem like it'd be helpful for providing a duration and fill for the animation.

So in short, I don't think I'm on the right track and would appreciate some pointers. If it's simple to replicate this JS code using `web-sys` and `js-sys` than I'd be indebted for a working example.